# script a list of websites to determine ciphers

Tags: command-line, bash, ssl

Have a list of websites I would like to check the ciphers. We will be using SSL decryption and want to see if I can in advance check the sites that will not support our decipher. We have some identified in our pilot. Saw on openssl I can check a website using a command

echo -n | openssl s_client -connect securepubads.g.doubleclick.net:443 >>securepubads_g_doubleclick_net.txt

Created a bash script (completely new at it). Ran a list of 100 commands and all are ok. When I have them in a script one after the other it seems to run wild and the commands fail. Added a sleep 5 inbetween each command but stil fails. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: no... work . want to see the ciphers of the highest hit sites and be able to exclude the ones that will not work with the decryption in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sample script to loop the requests:

```
for i in `cat file_with_list`;
do
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect $i >>securepubads_g_doubleclick_net.txt 
done
```

Also you can check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers) answer for script to loop for all ciphers